# Powershell CSV import to html in table

Tags: powershell, html, csv

I try convert an csv file to html with Powershell. It only takes the last line in the csv file and not all lines.

I am new to powershell, so hope someone can help me

---

```
$users = import-csv “C:\fso\names.csv”
$Report = ForEach ($item in $users)
{
    # I like to assign each property value to a simpler named variable, but it’s not necessary
    $firstName = $item.(“fornavn”)
    $lastName = $item.(“efternavn”)
}
$Report | ConvertTo-Html -Head $css -Body "<h1>Adresseliste</h1>`n<h5>Generated on $(Get-Date)</h5><table><tr><td><p>$firstname<p><td><p>$lastname</p></td></td></tr></table>" | Out-File "C:\fso\test.html"
```

Comment: Usually this question would be better suited for StackOverflow as it's not really within the scope of superuser. Usually you will find some information about what's on topic for an Exchange within the help section. If you haven't done already maybe take your time to read some of it like the [how to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) section. It will help you to get better and probably faster answers.

Answer (score 0):

You never really assign anything to `$Report`. You would need to do the HTML conversion within the loop. Currently you loop through each item and overwrite `$firstName` and `$lastName` with each iteration. You finish the loop and have the last value in it to use for your final output.

To provide an example:

Lets assume you want to sum the number one through ten using a loop. What you're currently doing is what follows.

```
$numbers = 1..10
$sum = 0
foreach($number in $numbers){
    $sum = $number
}
Write-Output $sum
```

You're assigning whatever number you're currently holding to be the sum. What you actually want to do in this case would be to add to the sum with each iteration.

```
$numbers = 1..10
$sum = 0
foreach($number in $numbers){
    $sum = $sum + $number
}
Write-Output $sum
```

What does that mean for your code? You need to generate your HTML within the loop. Your approach of assinging the output of the foreach loop to the `$repot` variable can actually be used for this. It's just currently not generating any output because you're just doing an assignment (that hopefully doesn't error). The following modification would give you a string with the output of each first and last name for each item. You could use this to generate your HTML. An alternative approach would be similar by using `$report` as a sum an adding to it each iteration.

```
$Report = ForEach ($item in $users)
{
    $firstName = $item.(“fornavn”)
    $lastName = $item.(“efternavn”)

    Write-Output $firstname,$lastName
}
```

P.S. be aware that [foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6) and [ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6) are different things. You will probably encounter the latter more often especially if you use the shorthand `%`. One major difference is that you can't use `continue` or `break` within the latter but instead would need to use another mechanism like `return`.